# Swift AVPlayer Won't Player MP4: Play Button With Line Through It

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

[image]

I am trying to player an mp4 video from the local file system on an ios app. The video is about an hour long and can be played on quicktime. I am able to play an mp4 if it is from the web (NSURL(string: "http:domain.com/vid.mp4")). I am playing the video like below:

```
    let steamingURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: video.filePath)! //valid path
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: steamingURL)
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = false

    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.player = player
    self.addChildViewController(PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.view)
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.view.frame = videoContainerView.frame
    PlayWorkoutViewController.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    player.play()
```

Do I need to change some of the settings to play the longer video? Thanks.

Comment: try using NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: <#T##String#>) instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the steamingURL is nil or not first

If you want to use NSURL(string: "xxx") initialiser please check the string starts with file://, otherwise use NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "xxxx") instead.

Comment: Oh ok I will try that once I get it to build. Thanks I bet that is the problem.

Comment: My issue was actually the opposite. I was trying to load a video from the web and getting the same result because I was using NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://...") instead of NSURL(string: "http://...").

Comment: Hi @c.dunalp, am unable to play the video even if am using URL(string: "http://...") and my app requirement is same as yours. Pls provide any alternative...Thanks